# The correct way to shorten long for statement to a maximum of 79 columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

My question is what's the most conventional way of making the following line of code:

```
self.steps = [setpoint_and_hold_time.setpoint for setpoint_and_hold_time in program.setpoints_and_hold_times]
```

to 79 character columns or less?

- According to PEP8, the maximum line length should be 79 characters.
- For long if statements I've used brackets but I'm not sure how I would use them here (if that's the solution).

Also, I assumed this line of code didn't need much background context, if it does please tell me and I'll edit in some classes that explain this line of code.

Thanks.

Comment: You can break lines using ` \ ` or maybe use a variable name with less characters ? (`setpoint_and_hold_time` is kinda big, especially for a temp variable in a comprehension)

Comment: You should try to reduce variables name length also. You probably don't need to name a variable `setpoint_and_hold_time`.

Comment: @PMende I thought that was just for docstrings and comments etc.

Comment: @Moosefeather Oops. Yes, you are totally correct! Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[black](https://github.com/ambv/black) will reformat as (PEP8 compliant and it is quite readable I think):

```
self.steps = [
    setpoint_and_hold_time.setpoint
    for setpoint_and_hold_time in program.setpoints_and_hold_times
]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
self.steps = [setpoint_and_hold_time.setpoint
              for setpoint_and_hold_time
              in program.setpoints_and_hold_times]
```

/shrug

Answer (score 5):

Given their limited scope, there's no need to give loop variables long names. I would shorten `setpoint_and_hold_time`.

```
self.steps = [sh.setpoint for sh in program.setpoints_and_hold_times]
```